# Objective-C iOS - how draw multiple dashed line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, draw

How can I draw multiple vertical dashed line in my view?

I tried to add border to a provisory view, like this:

```
    // line top
    UIView *line = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 730, 1)];
    //line.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:15.0/255.0f green:144.0/255.0f blue:190.0/255.0f alpha:1.0];

    CAShapeLayer *yourViewBorder = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    yourViewBorder.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:15.0/255.0f green:144.0/255.0f blue:190.0/255.0f alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    yourViewBorder.fillColor = nil;
    yourViewBorder.lineDashPattern = @[@2, @2];
    yourViewBorder.frame = line.bounds;
    yourViewBorder.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:line.bounds].CGPath;
    [line.layer addSublayer:yourViewBorder];
    [pdfview addSubview:line];
    //fine line top
```

Pdfview is the first view, I've to draw a lot of dashed line inside her.
Any other methods?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be more efficient you can apply CAReplicatorLayer. You don't need the UIView

1. Create the CAShapeLayer with dashed line path.
2. Add the line layer to CAReplicatorLayer
3. Add replicator to your pdf layer.

Here is the documentation
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/careplicatorlayer?language=objc